# Содержание C:\ при выполнение сценария javascript

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста.
Дело в том, что когда я нажимаю на ссылку со сценарием

```
<a href="/" onClick="elements()">elements html</a>
```

у меня при закрытие всплывающего окна, открывается новая страница с содержимым диска С

[image]

тоже самое получается когда я результат сценария пытаюсь отобразить на самой странице

В этом случае результата вообще не видно, открывается сразу это окно

Comment: Функция elements должна выполнить в конце.  

      window.event.returnValue=false;
      window.event.cancelBubble= true;
и похоже страницу Вы открываете минуя сервер, а просто как обычный файл в системе.

Comment: но ведь до этого всё нормально было

Comment: Извините ошибся в том, что должна сделать функция, поправил комментарий.

Comment: тоесть если эти две строки должны быть в самом конце функции?

Comment: Не забывайте, что у пользователя вполне может быть отключён js. Так что ваша ссылка должна вести не в случайное место.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в функции, а в

```
href="/"
```

Вы указываете корень, но не указываете корень чего. Браузер пытается открыть и показывает вам корень сайта ( в вашем случае корень диска С). Используйте

```
<base href="somesite.com/" target="_blank">
```

для задания точки отсчета или же устанавливайте более полные адреса в сами ссылки. Ответил более развернуто в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167792/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-javascript-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2) вопросе.