# Содержание C:\ при выполнение сценария javascript (часть 2)

Tags: javascript

я уже писал что при выполнение сценария javascript у меня открывается окно с содержанием диска с:/
[image]

Мне посоветовали в функцию вставлять 2 строки

window.event.returnValue=false;
window.event.cancelBubble= true;

и это помогло, но есть одно но. Меня напрягает каждый раз вставлять в новую функцию эти строки.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать как всё вернуть назад, ведь до этого мне не приходилось вписывать эти строки каждый раз для новой функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из прошлого вопроса:

```
<a href="/" onClick="elements()">elements html</a>
```

Зачем вы используете "/" в href? Какое назначение? Если не нужен переход по ссылке используйте

```
href="#", href="javascript:;", href="javascript:void(0);"
```

или любое подобное.
Если надо поставить ссылку в корень сайта - пропишите туда полный путь

```
href="somesite.com/"
```

Или же укажите в head

```
<base href="somesite.com/" target="_blank">
```

и дальше используйте ссылки так, как использовали

```
<a href="/" onClick="elements()">elements html</a>
```